# TextFormField disappears on click

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have form to grab info from User. But when I tap on TextFormField and keyboard shows it disappears.

https://youtu.be/UhVL2hqWOlQ

Here is my code:

```
class _AddInfoState extends State<AddInfo>{

  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = new GlobalKey();
  bool _validate = false;
  String strTitle;
  File fileImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body:new Container(
        child: new Form(
          key: _key,
          autovalidate: _validate,
          child: formUI(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget formUI(){
    return new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        //Title Field
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0),
          child:new TextFormField(
            style: styleTextField,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            autofocus: true,
            maxLength: 45,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Title',
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.title,
                  size: 30.0,
                  color: blueColor,
                )
            ),
            validator: validateTitle,
            onSaved: (String val) {
              strTitle = val;
            },
          ),
        ),                
      ],
      physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of how it looks before and after it dissapears, it'll make it easier to help you if we know what's happening visually as well.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding from the video, since you have used a scrollable `ListView` inside your form, the list is scrolling upward once the keyboard appears hence it disappears.

Try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in your Scaffold. This will make the keyboard appear as an overlay and won't push the content upward.

Example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body:new Container(
        child: new Form(
          key: _key,
          autovalidate: _validate,
          child: formUI(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following message was thrown during layout:
flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 295 pixels on the bottom.
flutter:
flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and

Comment: If I run the code you posted above, I am not getting the exception, but the exception is probably because the main `Container` was given an infinite height.
Try setting some finite height like `height: 200.0` for the `Container` and let me know if you still get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Container` which has the `TextFormField` in a `SizedBox` :

```
                new Form(
                autovalidate: false,
                key: _formKey,
                child: new Container(
                  height: orientation == Orientation.portrait ?  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height :  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2 ,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child:  new Column(
                    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 100.0,
                            child: new Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                             child:new TextFormField(
                             style: styleTextField,
                             keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                             autofocus: true,
                             maxLength: 45,
                             decoration: InputDecoration(
                             hintText: 'Enter Title',
                             prefixIcon: Icon(
                             Icons.title,
                             size: 30.0,
                             color: blueColor,
                           )
                         ),
                         validator: validateTitle,
                         onSaved: (String val) {
                           strTitle = val;
                         },
                       ),
                     ),          
                   )

                           ]
                         )
                       )
                     ]
                   )
                 )
               )
```

Comment: I used a `SizedBox` with a `Column` child, then I put the `TextFormField` inside it and it works for me. Try to add it, and tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: Ok let me tell you more details as I understands your solution is best for another scenario. 
I have a tab bar controller and for that I have created a separate class. In this class I have added a Form. That is not working as I need. For more info I have added a video too.

Comment: @CodeHunter I will show you the complete hierarchy of my form, I don't think putting it in a tab bar is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` and then change the `Column` to a `ListView`